# Is the following characterization of a finite set $A$ in a metric space true?

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be an infinite [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) with distance function $d$ such that there exists a $B \subseteq M$ bounded infinite set.

Is it true that

> $A\subseteq M$ is finite $\stackrel{?}{\leftrightarrow} \exists B\subseteq M$ bounded infinite and $\exists f:A\to B$ injective s.t.
> $$\inf_{\begin{matrix}\begin{matrix}a,b\in A \\ a\ne b\end{matrix}\end{matrix}} d(f(a),f(b)) \ne 0$$

$f$ can be thought of as a "packing" function that packs all the values of $A$ into a bounded set $B$. If we can pack the values in a way that even the closest ones are more than distance $0$ apart from each other ($d(f(a),f(b)) > 0$), then the original set $A$ couldn't have contained a "lot" of elements (it should be finite).

The $(\rightarrow)$ direction isn't too difficult to prove:

Let $|A|:=n$, then we can define the diameter of $B$ as the diameter of the largest distance that can fit into it:

$$\text{diam}(B) := \sup_{x,y \in B} d(x,y)$$

For a bounded infinite $B$, this has to be $>0$.

Then lining up the elements of $A$, equally separated by $\frac{\text{diam}(B)}{2n}$ (this is what the $f$ function will do), they will all fit into $B$ and their minimum distance is

$$\inf_{\begin{matrix}a,b\in A \\ a\ne b\end{matrix}} d(f(a),f(b)) = \min_{\begin{matrix}a,b\in A \\ a\ne b\end{matrix}} d(f(a),f(b)) = \frac{\text{diam}(B)}{2n} > 0 \quad \square$$

However, I'm struggling to prove the $(\leftarrow)$ direction. I think intuitively it should be true though. If not, then is there a packing of infinitely many elements where the minimum (infimum) distance between two elements is $>0$?

Comment: Your $\inf$ condition doesn't depend on $f$ or $B$, is that a mistake? Also, the "$\Rightarrow$" implication is clearly false when $M$ is finite to begin with: it doesn't even have an infinite subset $B$. Note that you never actually showed in your reasoning that such $B$ exists.

Comment: Yes, I will correct it. Thank you!

Comment: What if $M$ is a finite metric space? Such $M$ will not exist.

Comment: Right, then such a $B$ wouldn't exist. I suppose the question only works for infinite metric spaces.

Comment: Consider $A = \{0,1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$ and $B = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $f(0)=0, f(1/n) = n$. Then $A,B,f$ satify the RHS but $A$ is not finite.

Comment: @Didier $B$ has to be bounded though.

Comment: @DanielP this is not necessarily true even when $M$ is infinite. Because it doesn't have to have an infinite bounded subset, e.g. $M=\mathbb{N}$ with the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @DanielP You're right my above comment is not a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the issue mentioned in the comment there is another problem, closely related to the fact that in a metric space closed and bounded sets don't have to be compact. Take for instance the set
$$H=\{a=(a_1,a_2,\dots) \ | \ a_i \in \mathbf{R} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 < \infty \}$$ with metric
$$d(a,b)=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-b_n)^2}.$$

You can define a sequence $a^{(1)},a^{(2)},a^{(3)},\dots$ by taking $a^{(m)}$ to be the point with a $1$ in position $m$ and $0$'s elsewhere. The distance between any two distinct points in this sequence is $\sqrt{2}$, and the whole sequence is bounded (all are of distance $1$ from $0$) but it is not finite. So the implication $\Leftarrow$ fails.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great counterexample! Now would it be alright to ask the same question by editing the post, but instead of $\exists B \subseteq M$, I change it to $\forall B \subseteq M$; or should I make that a separate question?

Comment: @DanielP I wouldn't edit this post to change your question unless you want me to delete my answer :). It's happened to me that I have answered a question, the questioner then changes it to a different question, and a little while later I get downvoted without explanation, but presumably because my answer no longer addresses the new version of the question.

Comment: Alright, you're right. I'll ask a separate question. Your post correctly answers my current issue.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all I assume that the infimum is taken over $a\neq b$, otherwise it is always trivially $0$.

The "$\Leftarrow$" implication is not true. It is enough to find a bounded infinite subset $B$ such that the infimum over distances of its distinct elements is positive. Take $B=M$ to be any infinite set with the discrete $d(x,y)=1$ metric.

The "$\Rightarrow$" implication is also not true, even when $M$ is assumed to be infinite. Because it doesn't have to have an infinite bounded subset, e.g. $\mathbb{N}$ with the Euclidean distance. But if $M$ has an infinite bounded subset, say $C\subseteq M$ then it is true. You simply take $B:=A\cup C$ and $f$ to be the inclusion $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Am I the only person who always upvotes questions I bother to answer? Sometimes it seems so, although I guess you are an extreme case---someone with 30K reputation but less than 400 total votes!

Comment: @Stephen yeah, I suppose I don't care that much about votes. Not only for others, but for myself as well. I just like to answer questions. :) Note that I have around 2.5 more points than you, but 4 times answers. Even though you've been here almost twice as long.

Comment: Well, I am not very active; that explains the relatively small number of answers (which are also concentrated in very specialized areas; I rarely answer questions like this one where there are lots of people who could answer... unless I am especially bored :)). My impression is that voting is essential for the proper functioning of the site, but I also think turning math into a game for collecting points is potentially harmful.

Comment: @Stephen I truely don't know what is essential for the site and what is not. Plus I don't really care that much. As I said: I just like to answer questions. What do you mean by "harmful"? As long as answers are correct, I'm completely fine with people doing that.