# Is the following characterization of a finite set $A$ in a metric space true? (with $\forall B \subseteq M$ instead of $\exists B \subseteq M$)

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, metric-spaces

I have asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398915/is-the-following-characterization-of-a-finite-set-a-in-a-metric-space-true) question previously, which turned out to be false. My current question is very similar, but might completely change the answer, so I'm posting it separately.

The difference is $\forall B\subseteq M$ in the question, instead of $\exists B\subseteq M$.

---

Let $(M,d)$ be an infinite [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) with distance function $d$ such that there exists a $B \subseteq M$ bounded infinite set.

Is it true that

> $A\subseteq M$ is finite $\stackrel{?}{\leftrightarrow} \forall B\subseteq M$ bounded infinite $\exists f:A\to B$ injective s.t.
> $$\inf_{\begin{matrix}\begin{matrix}a,b\in A \\ a\ne b\end{matrix}\end{matrix}} d(f(a),f(b)) \ne 0$$

$f$ can be thought of as a "packing" function that packs all the values of $A$ into a bounded set $B$. If we can pack the values in a way that even the closest ones are more than distance $0$ apart from each other ($d(f(a),f(b)) > 0$), then the original set $A$ couldn't have contained a "lot" of elements (it should be finite).

---

The $(\rightarrow)$ direction isn't too difficult to prove:

Let $|A|:=n$, then we can define the diameter of $B$ as the largest distance that can fit into it:

$$\text{diam}(B) := \sup_{x,y \in B} d(x,y)$$

For a bounded infinite $B$, this has to be $>0$.

Then lining up the elements of $A$, equally separated by $\frac{\text{diam}(B)}{2n}$ (this is what the $f$ function will do), they will all fit into $B$ and their minimum distance is

$$\inf_{\begin{matrix}a,b\in A \\ a\ne b\end{matrix}} d(f(a),f(b)) = \min_{\begin{matrix}a,b\in A \\ a\ne b\end{matrix}} d(f(a),f(b)) = \frac{\text{diam}(B)}{2n} > 0 \quad \square$$

---

However, I'm struggling to prove the $(\leftarrow)$ direction. I think intuitively it should be true though. If not, then is there a packing of infinitely many elements where the minimum (infimum) distance between two elements is $>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "$\Leftarrow$" implication is still not true. Just like in the other question, the same counterexample (given by me btw) works.

Consider $M$ to be any infinite set with the discrete $d(x,y)=1$ metric. First of all note that every subset of $M$ is bounded. Then take $A$ to be any countable subset of $M$. Now $A$ embeds into any infinite subset of $M$, simply by the cardinality argument. Furthermore the infimum is always $1$, but it is not finite.

Comment: Thank you, again. I need to broaden my view of metric spaces, as not all distance functions work like Euclidean distance. I will ponder the question in the case where $d$ *is* the Euclidean distance however. I think in that case it should hold.